# Upload XLS files in EE3?

Tags: ee3, config, xml

I can't find a way to whitelist the mime type that will allow the user to upload XLS files.

I've tried all of these settings but I'm still being blocked:

```
$config['mime_whitelist_additions'] = array(
  'application/octet-stream', // .xls
  'application/msexcel', // .xls
  'application/x-msexcel', // .xls
  'application/x-ms-excel', // .xls
  'application/x-excel', // .xls
  'application/x-dos_ms_excel', // .xls
  'application/xls', // .xls
  'application/x-xls', // .xls
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml', // .xltx, .xls
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // .xlsx, .xls
  'text/xls' // .xls
);
```

Has anyone solved this?